# Função load() abrir iframe

Tags: javascript

Tenho o código abaixo que funciona perfeitamente.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadModal(){
        $('#injetada').load('teste.html');
    }
</script> 

<a onclick="loadModal()" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#1">Verificar</a>
 <div id="1" class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id='injetada' width="900px" height="600px"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Entretanto, gostaria que a página fosse aberta com um iframe. Ou seja, em:

```
$('#injetada').load('teste.html');
```

pudesse ser

```
$('#injetada').load('<iframe src="teste.html" width="900" height="600"></iframe>');
```

Imagino que estou usando a sintaxe errada para chamar um iframe aqui, mas não encontrei nenhum site com a sintaxe certa. Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Já tentou criar variavel com seu iframe e depois no load chama ela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode simplesmente injetar um HTML com um `iframe` na `div` sem a necessidade de usar `.load()`:

```
function loadModal(){
   $('#injetada').html('<iframe src="teste.html" width="900" height="600"></iframe>');
}
```

> Observando que esta sintaxe `width` e `height` abaixo que está usando
>   é inválida:

```
<div id='injetada' width="900px" height="600px"></div>
```

Se quer setar as dimensões da `div`, você pode fazer de duas maneiras:

**Inline:**

```
<div id='injetada' style="width: 900px; height: 600px;"></div>
```

**Ou no CSS:**

```
#injetada{
   width: 900px;
   height: 600px;
}
```

## Exemplo JSFiddle

Comment: Obrigado amigo, funcionou perfeitamente! Muito obrigado!!!